# Does Redeploying a Windows VM on Azure Retain your Data and Applications?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I am unable to start my Windows VM on Azure and I want to try the Redeploy feature built into the Azure portal.  But, I want to be sure that I won't lose my data and applications by using this feature.  Can anyone please confirm that the redeploy feature will keep my data and apps?

Comment: `the virtual machine will be restarted and you will lose any data on the temporary drive. While the redeployment is in progress, the virtual machine will be unavailable.` - `When you redeploy a VM, it moves the VM to a new node within the Azure infrastructure and then powers it back on, retaining all your configuration options and associated resources.`

Answer (score 3):

The redeploy feature stops your VM and starts it on a new host. Any data on C: or on any storage account backed drives will be retained. Anything you stored on the temporary D drive will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please confirm that the redeploy feature will keep my data
>   and apps?

When you redeploy a VM, it moves the VM to a new node within the Azure infrastructure and then powers it back on, retaining all your configuration options and associated resources.

It is sure that you will not lose any data on your VM.(except driver D:)

**Notes:After you redeploy a VM, the temporary disk is lost and dynamic IP addresses associated with virtual network interface are updated.** More information about temporary disk please refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/06/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines/).

More information about redeploy VM please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-redeploy-to-new-node).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.